# Show "empty" TDateTimePicker

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

How can I show an "empty" TDateTimePicker in Delphi 2010 (that is, hide the display of the date so the control appears empty).  I know about the trick of setting the format to show the epoch, but with Delphi 2010 running on Windows 7 the string "A.D." appears in the control when I do this.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try setting the `format` to a blank space Value.

```
DateTimePicker1.Format:=' ';
```

and then in the `OnChange` method set the format again

```
procedure TForm1.DateTimePicker1Change(Sender: TObject);
begin
DateTimePicker1.Format:=ShortDateFormat;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works perfectly.  I use the single space to suppress any display and an empty string (no space) to set it back to the default format.

Comment: Does that still work for allowing the user to enter a date with the keyboard?

Answer (score 2):

You could also try:

```
DateTimePicker1.Format := '__/__/____';
```

That way it looks to the end user like a date is required.

Comment: That is obviously for the American date format mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when looking to see how to handle this.

I'm actually using a `TJvDateTimePicker` primarily because it displays week numbers in the drop down.  I was going to use the 'format trick' suggested by @RRUZ, but have found that the `TJvDateTimePicker` includes a couple of extra published properties, `NullDate` and `NullText` which are used to implement the "format trick".

In my form's constructor I place the code:

```
dtpOne.NullDate := 0;
dtpOne.NullText := ' '; // empty string doesn't work
```

All seems to work as you'd expect.

Answer (score 0):

In Delphi 10 the way to enable the TDateTimePicker again is:

```
DateTimePicker1.format := EmptyStr;
```

The ShortDateFormat is no more present in system.SysUtils

Comment: `ShortDateFormat` together with other format settings were earlier (e.g. Delphi 7) global variables in the `SysUtils` unit. Now they are fields of a global `TFormatSettings` record, called  `FormatSettings`. IOW, to use the globally declared `ShortDateFormat` you must write `FormatSettings.ShortDateFormat`.